# Moving Object "in or out" along the z axis using Sin(time) or Cos(time)

Tags: unity, c#, transformation, trigonometry

I am new to game development, and I have successfully moved an object in the x and y directions using Mathf.Sin(x) and Mathf.Cos(x). But I'm unable to move same object in the z-direction (in or out).

This is the code I am using:

```
public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    [SerializeField] float amplitude = -2f;
    [SerializeField] float frequency = 2f;

    void Update()
    {    
        float x = Mathf.Cos(Time.time * frequency) * amplitude;
        float y = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * amplitude;
        float z = transform.position.z;

        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

What changes should I make to move my object in the z direction?

Comment: Presumably you tried doing the same thing to your `z` variable that you did to `x` or `y`? How did the results differ from what you wanted? (Also, note that your question contains no UnityScript, which is an old JavaScript-like language that Unity has not supported for half a decade. Be sure to read the tag descriptions when tagging your question)

Comment: @DMGregory I created C# script in Unity3D and attached it to my Unity3D object, yes same thing i want to do with my Z. i don't know how its Java?

Comment: What I mean is that you can simply take the code that comes after `float x =` and paste it after `float z =`, no? What goes wrong when you try that?

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for correcting me, agreed